# laravel one to many to many relationship

Tags: php, orm, eloquent, laravel-5

Hi I am new to Laravel and currently in am using Laravel 5.2. I am trying to create an application where I have  posts and comments and comments have replies table and have the following model.

**Post model**

```
public function comments() {
     return $this->hasMany('App\Comment');
}
```

**Comment model**

```
public function posts() {
   return $this->belongsTo('App\Post');
}

public function replies() {
   return $this->hasMany('App\Reply');
}
```

**Reply Model**

```
public function comments() {
   return $this->belongsTo('App\Comment');
}
```

What I want to achieve :

Post with comment with replies for Post

**post -> many comments -> many replies**

I am able to get comments with following

```
$posts = Post::with('comments')->get();
```

But dont know how to get comments with reply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do

```
Post::with('comments.replies')->get()
```

Additionally, you should always be able to get replies from a comment like this: `->replies`. Just be careful that if you have not eager loaded all the replies you might get hundreds of queries to the database, each comment will send a query to retrieve replies. If you retrieve all the comments like the query above you will retrieve all the replies at once and Laravel will map them to appropriate comments.

Also there are some good examples for you to read from the laravel docs: [Eloquent: Relationships - Eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading)